# How to work with logging in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I use PySpark 2.2 and I want to add logging. This is how I do it:

```
log4j = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(log4j.Level.WARN)
logger = log4j.LogManager.getLogger("logger")
logger.warn("Starting")
```

However, when I run `yarn logs -applicationId ...`, then I do not see my log messages. What am I doing wrong and where the messages are saved? How can I specify the path (in python code) where I want to save `*.log` file?

Comment: YARN reads stdout, stderr, as well as syslog. If you want the Spark output, you should go check the Spark UI for the executor/driver process, which will redirect you to YARN containers

Comment: Also, in your `yarn-site.xml` of the cluster, you will have set a YARN log path... However, it is by container and application. You can't just tell Spark to write to a single location on a local filesystem with YARN

Comment: So, can I then generate logs without Yarn in order to get `*.log` file? The idea is that logs are later analyzed with Kibana.

Comment: I never said you couldn't get the logs. Just that they are distributed across all the possible YARN NodeManagers.

Comment: @cricket_007: I checked Spark UI, but I cannot find my logs there.

Comment: First, I would start with just `print("Starting")`, then you check `stdout` of the application. Then, I would use `getRootLogger()` to log things, not the `.getLogger("logger")`

Comment: @cricket_007: What's the diff between `getRootLogger()` and `getLogger("logger-poc1")`?

Comment: The latter is supposed to be the Logger instance, configured by the `log4j.xml` file in the spark classpath. I do not know those names off the top of my head, therefore, start with the root logger

Comment: If you see no logs at all, though, then log4j isn't configured correctly.